# Unable to Group by

Tags: sql, db2

I am pulling data using QTODBC 7.0 from DB2, to eventually put it in Power By. I am fairly new to writing queries but I know a few things here and there. I am unable to group by on hand quantity.

```
select

htpart,
(htqty-htqtyc) as OnHand

from seri

where htplnt = 'GC'
and htsts = 'A'

group by htpart, htqty, htqtyc
```

The result is

```
      HTPART             ONHand
.1249 X .250 DOWEL      6.00000
.1249 X .250 DOWEL      9.00000
.1249 X .250 DOWEL      50.00000
.1249 X .438 DOWEL      86.00000
.1251 X .500 DOWEL      28.00000
.210 BN70               2000.00000
.210 BN70               382.00000
.210 VT70               40.00000
.250 BN70               26.60000
.250 BN70               145.00000
.275 EPDM50             6642.00000
.275 EPDM50             7107.00000
```

I would like to see the rows with the same part number "HTPART"  as one row with the sum of the OnHand as listed

```
     HTPART                     ONHAND
.1249 X .250 DOWEL              65.00000
.1249 X .438 DOWEL              86.00000
.1251 X .500 DOWEL              28.00000
.210 BN70                       2382.00000
.210 VT70                       40.00000
.250 BN70                       171.60000
.275 EPDM50                     13749.00000
```

I have to mention.

The Seri table contains Columns that are not unite as HTLOTN for batch or lot number.
That is why the result shows as multiple items for the same part number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for `SUM()`:

```
select htpart, sum(htqty-htqtyc) as OnHand
from seri
where htplnt = 'GC' and htsts = 'A'
group by htpart;
```

Note that if you want one row per `htpart`, then that should be the only column in the `GROUP BY`.